# linux driver installation error - “/lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5/build: No such file or directory. Stop.”

Tags: linux

I got an error "/lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5/build: No such file or directory. Stop." while installing moxa driver, following is the shell screen shot. please help me for a resolution. Thanks for your time !

```
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# pwd
/root/moxa/mxu11x0/driver
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# ls
Makefile  mxu1110_fw.h  mxu1130_fw.h  mxu1131_fw.h  mxu1150_fw.h  mxu1151_fw.h  mxu11x0.c  mxu11x0.h  usb-serial.h
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# make clean
rm -f *.o
rm -f .*.o.cmd
rm -f *.symvers
rm -rf ./.tmp_versions
rm -f mxu11x0.mod*
rm -f .mxu11x0*
rm -f mxu11x0.ko
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# make install
  *******************************************************************
  # MOXA UPort 1110/1130/1150/1150I USB to Serial Hub Driver v1.2 #
  #                for Linux Kernel 2.6.x                           #
  #                                                                 #
  #               release date : 03/23/2009                         #
  *******************************************************************
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5/build SUBDIRS=/root/moxa/mxu11x0/driver modules 
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [module] Error 2
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# 
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# uname -a
Linux lnx149-252 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:43 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386     GNU/Linux
[root@lnx149-252 driver]# uname -r
2.6.18-194.el5
[root@lnx149-252 driver]#
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the source code to this driver, and you're running a very old system, but it's probably just the Makefile being configured incorrectly to not run the default build options prior to installing.

Because so many Makefiles do this wrong, my usual procedure is thus:

```
make clean
make
make install
```

The second `make` invocation calls the default build step (`all` by default) which builds the object files. `make install` might not work if it doesn't depend on `all` or whatever rule does compilation. Nowhere in your shell output does anything indicate to me that it's actually compiling anything or even trying to, so this is most likely the solution.